# How to stop service while running the service?

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

In my application i am running the service in the background by using the following code.

```
Service myser=new Intent(EmailRegistrationActivity.this, BackgroundService.class);
startService(myser);
```

And in my service class i am using AsyncTask class. In that AsyncTask class i have to get the sms and mms from the device and posting to my local server.In between the process,the user want to sign out.So in that sign out method i want to stop the service.

And this is the service class

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service{
@Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
}
 @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        if(startId>1)
        {
            if(CheckInternetConnection.isOnline(BackgroundService.this))
            {
         dob=new Doinback();
         dob.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        }else{
            //check2=preferences.
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("checkbackground", true);
        editor.commit();

        }
        }

      return 1;
    }
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    }
    public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    public void onStop() {

        this.stopSelf();

    }
    public void onPause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

         super.onDestroy();

         Log.e("Destroy=======@@@@@@@","method calling");
         dob.cancel(false);

          while(strtId>0){
              this.stopSelf(strtId);
              strtId--;
          }

         onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {

    }
}
```

And this is the asynctask class

```
class Doinback extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long>{
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    { 

    }
    protected Long doInBackground(URL... arg0) {

    if(!isCancelled())
    {
    try {   
        strResLastmessage_time = UrltoValue.getValuefromUrl(DataUrls.lastmessage_time + "userid="+strUserId);
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(strResLastmessage_time);
        strLastMessage_time = jsonObj.getString("lastdatetime");            
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(BackgroundService.this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putLong("msgtime", Long.parseLong(strLastMessage_time));
        editor.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
    //      e.printStackTrace();
        }
        messages.clear();
        readSmsFromDevice();
        checkMessages();    
     }
     return null;
    }
    protected void onCancelled() {    
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
        //check=preferences.getBoolean("checkbackup", true);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("checkbackup", true);
        editor.putBoolean("checkbackground", true);     
        editor.commit();     
    }
}//async class
```

And in this asyntask class i am using readsmsfromdevice method and checkmessages method to get the data from device and post to to service.But my requirement is whenever user want to logout, the service have to stop.So that i am using the following code to stop service and also stopped asynctask.

```
BackgroundService.dob.cancel(true);
getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(), BackgroundService.class));
```

But it not working,still in background the proceess is continue.Please suggest me how to stop this service.Thanks In Advance...

Comment: The service is stopping. The AsyncTask is running in another thread, that's why it continues to execute. The best you can do is call `canel()` on it, which you already do. You could try checking `isCancelled()` again inside the `try` block, if there's a sensible place to do so...

Comment: where to check iscancelled() method

Comment: inside `doInBackground()`. You are already calling this once before the `try` block starts, but you can always do it again later after some work has partially finished.

Comment: but my problem is stop the process which is running in the background

Comment: Then you need a mechanism that has better guarantees about stopping than `AsyncTask` does. Given how difficult that is in concurrent programming in general, I think you are going to spend more time than it's worth to do so. If the task is running for a very long time, then you should try to break up the work and check `isCancelled()` more often. If it only runs for a short time and isn't showing the user anything, I don't see the harm in letting `doInBackground` finish processing.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the right method "this.stopSelf()". I once had this problem and after adding return Service.START_NOT_STICKY it worked. Could you just add this code on onStartCommand method and check if it works:

```
return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reponse..but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

What you need is IntentService.[From docs:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

> IntentService is a base class for Services that handle asynchronous
>   requests (expressed as Intents) on demand. Clients send requests
>   through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed,
>   handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself
>   when it runs out of work.

Refer this link on how to use IntentService:

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics--mobile-6183